# Django questionnaire with several score categories per answer

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am very new to Django (and definitely rusty with HTML) and basically went through the official tutorial a couple of times. I am planning on creating a simple questionnaire with a list of questions, these questions can have several answers and each answer has a specific score for various categories. In the end the points for each category are added and depending on the score a message is displayed.

<s>I am a bit stuck on how to display the answers for each question in a template however.</s> I am also unsure how to calculate the final score: should I create a new class in my models to store the score? Or should I just do it in views.py (I would prefer this solution for now, I don't need to store the score in the DB and I don't need to login a user)?

Here is what I have so far:

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    questionnaire_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionnaire_text

class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    C1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    C2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class QuestionnaireInstance(models.Model):
    taker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    questionnaire_taken = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    C1_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    C2_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N1_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N2_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N3_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    N4_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.taker)
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question, Questionnaire, Choice

def index(request):
    latest_questionnaire_list = Questionnaire.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('test/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_questionnaire_list': latest_questionnaire_list
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def detail (request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('test/detail.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def results (request):
    questionnaire_instance = QuestionnaireInstance.objects.get(taker=request.user)
    answer_instance = Choice.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
       questionnaire_instance.C1_score=+ answer_instance.values_list('C1',flat=True)[selected answer] #No clue how to call on the score of the specifically selected answer here
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'test'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('detail/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('results/', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

detail.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if latest_question_list %}
{% for item in latest_question_list %}
<h1>{{ item.question_text}}</h1>
    {% for answer in item.choice_set.all %}
    <form action="{% url 'oritest:results'%}" method="post">
    <p>
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer" id="answer"
        value="{{ answer.id }}">
    <label for="answer">{{ answer.choice_text }}
    </label><br>
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


<input type="submit" value="Confirm">
<input type="button" onclick="history.back();" value="Back">

</form>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to:

<s>1) Have `detail.html` displaying each question and its answers with radio button.</s>

2) Add the score (probably in my function `results` in `views.py` and display it in `results.html`) and do something based on that score.

**Edit:** I have solved the first issue by myself (see the code for `detail.html`). I might play around with crispy forms later to make it nicer but so far it **looks** like I wanted it to. I still have to figure out the scoring system though.

I have added the `QuestionnaireInstance` class to `models.py` to store the scores of `Choice`. I assume I have to:

1) Instantiate (for example )C1_score and C1 in `results` within my views.

2) Have something like `C1_score =+ C1` also in `results`.

3) Display something (for example the user score and a picture) in results.html depending on C1_score.

I am uncertain of the syntax for instantiating C1_score depending on the User though.

**Edit2:** Is there any piece of information I have to add to get a nudge?

Answer (score 1):

For the form itself I would highly recommend crispy forms.  They look nice and will save a bit of work.

I would suggest that you store the correct answers in the database to make it easier to score and also create a response model to store the submitted answers.  Then after each question you would pass the response pk through the success_url to the results view that renders the results template.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get my detail.html to look like I wanted it to (see edit above). I have also created a new  ```QuestionnaireInstance``` class in my models to store each value of my ```Choice``` class. I now have to figure out how to send the values of the answers to the ```QuestionnaireInstance``` in the DB by submitting the form.